# Unity 2D Standard Movement Script Edit

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am using Unity 2D and am quiet new to this. I am trying to make a multiplayer platformer, and have started so. When I test my networking, however, all players match up to one input. Is there any way to edit the standard movement script to handle multiple user inputs, per build? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do the following it should solve the problem:

```
void Update () {
      if (!isLocalPlayer) 
          return;

      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) {
          ...code here
```

This means that the code after this if-statement will only be processed on the local player.

Comment: "The name 'isLocalPlayer' does not exist in current context." BTW I switched over to a 3D game, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I was under the impression that this is a UNET network game? ...if it is make sure you use: "using UnityEngine.Networking;" and "public class xxxxxxx : NetworkBehaviour {". XXXX being the name of your script.